# How to show more than 1 Stats panel in Three.js, side by side

Tags: three.js

Only if it's possible; for example one panel for FPS and another one for MS

Thanks, best regards

Comment: Please write a proper question with a title summarizing what you want to achieve and a question body which is actually a valid question. The body is not supposed to be a continuation of the sentence started in the title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple:

```js
var stats1 = new Stats();
stats1.showPanel(0); // Panel 0 = fps
stats1.domElement.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;';
document.body.appendChild(stats1.domElement);

var stats2 = new Stats();
stats2.showPanel(1); // Panel 1 = ms
stats2.domElement.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;top:0px;left:80px;';
document.body.appendChild(stats2.domElement);
```

And then in your main loop

```js
stats1.update();
stats2.update();
```

stats.js r17

Comment: Thank you. It's just what I was trying to acheive.

Comment: It is relatively easy to show multiple panels with the current implementation without having multiple Stats instances: https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/issues/115#issuecomment-993264168